# Why is a new session created before I login?

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat, spring-security

I have created a web app that uses Spring Security (3.2) login prompt. I run the app in Tomcat 7. I use the Tomcat manager to monitor sessions.
It is a Vaadin app, using a Vaadin servlet. No JSP pages are used.

Now...

1. I have a freshly started Tomcat with a freshly deployed .war.
2. I open a web browser and enter the url for the app and press enter which lands me on the login page of said app.
3. I can see in the Tomcat manager that 1 session has been created. Note that I haven't even tried logging in yet.
4. I close the app browser tab and the browser itself and re-open it (ie. effectively deleting any sessions data) and enter the url again and press enter.
5. I can see in the Tomcat manager that yet another session has been created. There is now a total of 2 sessions. Note that I still haven't even tried logging in.

Is this intended behaviour (prevention of some kind of session fixation attack) or have I simply configured something wrong?

Comment: Is your login page is a jsp or a simple html page  ??

Comment: If you are visiting JSP pages, then you need to know that they create session object (if it doesn't exist) by default. If you wan't to turn off this mechanism add `<%@ page session="false" %>` directive.

Comment: I realize now that I didn't provide all necessary information for troubleshooting this issue. Please see my updated original post for more details.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Oh, now I see what you mean. Yes, it is plain html. Like I mentioned in the original post it is in fact Spring Security's own login page (i.e. I haven't been messing with it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short version is that login processes that use a login page need to create session to store the target page.

The longer version is that the login process (assuming successful authentication) will be something along these lines:

1. User agent requests /some/secure/page
2. Container checks for authenticated user
3. User not authenticated so container starts login process
4. Container creates a session
5. Container adds target page URL (/some/secure/page) to session
6. Container redirects user to login page
7. User logs in
8. Container validates credentials
9. Container changes ID of session (to prevent session fixation)
10. Container gets target page URL from session
11. Container redirects user to target page
12. User agent requests target page
13. Container checks for authenticated user
14. User is authenticated so container displays requested page

Without the session the container has no way to track which (of the potentially many) pages requiring authentication the user asked for and therefore no way to redirect them to the requested page after authentication completes.

Comment: Extraordinary answer! It all seems very obvious now. Thanks a lot, Mark!

Answer (score 1):

The session is not directly related to spring-security, although spring-security can be creating it. The session is created by the servlet container on the first getSession(). Can be spring-security or any other code that runs during that first request and calls getSession().

Nonetheless, if that worries you, spring-security can be configured to replace that first session with a "fresh" one when you authenticate. More info [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/SessionFixationProtectionStrategy.java).

I hope I have helped clarify things for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think you just explained the *how* in my question, which is also very useful information indeed. However, it seems like Spring Security (in this case) creates a new session (and thus preventing session fixation attacks) automatically upon login (and logout) without having to implement it programmatically.

Comment: Yes, spring-security supports it out of the box. Glad it helped.